# Can't load resx file in code

Tags: c#, .net, localization, resx

I have a C# library (MyApp.ServiceLayer) and I want to access a common resx (/Resources/global.en-GB.resx) file from another library (MyApp.Common). I've added a reference from ServiceLayer to Common.

In the /bin/Debug folder of ServiceLayer I have (amongst others):

- MyApp.Common.dll
- en-gb/MyApp.Common.resources.dll.
- /Resources/global.en-GB.resx

Reflector tells me that MyApp.Common.resources.dll has a Resources folder and a resource file: MyApp.Common.Resources.global.en-GB.resources

This code returns "could not load assembly" error.

```
ResourceManager resource = new ResourceManager("resources.global", Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("MyApp.Common.resource")));
```

Why can't I get to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loading by AssemblyName only works if the resource file has been loaded into the current AppDomain.

Use the method ***LoadFrom()* instead of *Load()*** to load the assembly from a file:

```
ResourceManager resource = new ResourceManager("resources.global", Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\full\path\of\the\assembly\MyApp.Common.resources.dll"));
```